# Running command by clicking datagrid checkbox?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have the following datagrid:

```
<asp:datagrid id="rep_orders" runat="server"OnRowCommand="rep_orders_RowCommand">                          
<columns>                           
    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Complete" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="Smaller" ItemStyle-Font-Size="Smaller">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="checkedAll" OnCheckChanged="checkedAll_CheckedChanged">
            </asp:CheckBox>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="checked" runat="server" OnCheckChanged="Check_Clicked" AutoPostBack="true"/>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateColumn>

    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="order" HeaderText="Order" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="Smaller" ItemStyle-Font-Size="Smaller" />
    </columns>
</asp:datagrid>
```

It gets filled up with a sql query, so I get a list of checkboxes and order #s.  When I click a checkbox though, the on command function doesn't get triggered. Here's my function:

```
Sub rep_orders_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewCommandEventArgs)
    If e.CommandName = "Check_Clicked" Then
            //do stuff
    End If
End Sub
```

I've also tried creating a sub called "Check_Clicked" which also didn't work

```
Sub Check_Clicked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridItemEventArgs)
    //do stuff
End Sub
```

I couldn't put "handles" on the 2nd one because it complained `handles clause requires a withevents`

I know triggers within datagrids are handled differently from standalone inputs but I couldn't find anything other than what I already tried.  Anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: row command and mostly for buttons. The Check_Clicked should be called since it's in the control property (no need to use handles). If Check_Clicked isn't called, then it's probable because your grid isn't binded at the time the event needs to be called. I see you have a "check all" at the top, that won't be executed properly because as soon as the first checkbox is checked, a postback will occur. Maybe handling checkbox change event on the server isn't a good idea.

Comment: You only have `AutoPostBack="true"` for your rows. Have you tried putting that on your grid?